# sort file and folders in dropbox

Tags: android, dropbox

I am implementing dropbox core api in my app.I want to show the folders first and then files when the dropbox files bind in listview.

I am using following code:

```
private ArrayList<Entry> files,onlyfiles;
private ArrayList<String> dir;
public void setLoggedIn(final boolean loggedIn) {
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(DropboxDownload.this, null,
                "Retrieving data...");
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Constants.mLoggedIn = loggedIn;
                if (loggedIn) {
                    int i = 0;
                    com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI.Entry dirent;

                    try {
                        dirent = mApi.metadata(DIR, 1000, null, true, null);
                        files = new ArrayList<com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI.Entry>();
                        onlyfiles = new ArrayList<com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI.Entry>();
                        dir = new ArrayList<String>();
                        for (com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI.Entry ent : dirent.contents) {
                            if(ent.isDir){
                            files.add(ent);
                            }
                            else{
                            onlyfiles.add(ent);
                            }
                            files.addAll(onlyfiles);
                            dir.add(new String(files.get(i++).path));
                        }
                        i = 0;
                        pd.dismiss();
                        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

                    } catch (DropboxException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        pd.dismiss();
                    }
                }
                pd.dismiss();
            }
        }).start();

    }
```

But the above code causes a file to repeat several times in the list.Ehat is the problem??

Comment: Do away completely with `onlyfiles`. Rename dir to dirs. Remove statement `dir.add(new String(files.get(i++).path));` All you need in the loop is `if(ent.isDir){ dirs.add(ent); } else{ files.add(ent);}`. After that combine in one list for an adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
entries = new ArrayList<com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI.Entry>();

dirs = new ArrayList<String>(); // list of all directories
files = new ArrayList<String>(); // list of all files

// enumerate all entries (both files and directories)
for (com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI.Entry ent : dirent.contents) {
    // put directories into dirs
    if(ent.isDir) { dirs.add(ent); }

    // put files into files
    else { files.add(ent); }
}

// add all the directories first
entries.addAll(dirs);

// then add all the files
entries.addAll(files);
```

Comment: If you solved it, it would have been nice for you to say so here so people would know you didn't need any more help.

Comment: sorry sir...it had been a hectic schedule...so could`nt post the answer